# How to get the maximum interim value of a parameter in a select statement in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the maximum interim value of a parameter in a select statement in sql server?
Example:
I have a table userconnection that contains the login and logout time as below:

```
action, time, user
Login, 2013-24-11 13:00:00, a
Login, 2013-24-11 13:30:00, b
Login, 2013-24-11 14:00:00, c
Logout, 2013-24-11 14:10:00, b
...
...
...
```

Can anyone help me with the query below to show max concurrent users at any time during the day (=3 from the above example set) and current time of the day (=2 from the above example set?

```
[select DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, 0, time)) calanderday,
    sum(case when action = 'Login' then 1 when action = 'Logout' then -1
        else 0 end) concurrentuser,
    max of(concurrentuser interim values) maxconcurrentuser
   from userconnection
  where time > sysdate - 1        
group by DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, 0, time))
order by calanderday]
```

I would much appreciate any help with how to get 
max of(concurrentuser interim values) maxconcurrentuser?? in the above query without using user defined functions etc, just using inline queries.

Comment: Why is it 2, and not 2:10? During that entire period, there are 3 users logged in. What happens if there are *multiple* periods with a maximum number of concurrent users?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: It should show the maximum number of concurrent users at any time during last 24 hours.  The posted example query only shows the users connected at the time the query is run in the day but not the maximum in the day. (Sql server 2008)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work, but obviously you've only given us minimal sample data to work from:

```
;With PairedEvents as (
    select a.[user],a.time as timeIn,b.time as TimeOut
    from
        userconnection a
            left join
        userconnection b
            on
                a.[user] = b.[user] and
                a.time < b.time and
                b.action = 'logout'
            left join
        userconnection b_anti
            on
                a.[user] = b_anti.[user] and
                a.time < b_anti.time and
                b_anti.time < b.time and
                b_anti.action = 'logout'
    where
        a.action = 'Login' and
        b_anti.action is null
), PossibleMaxima as (
    select pe.timeIn,COUNT(*) as Cnt
    from
        PairedEvents pe
            inner join
        PairedEvents pe_all
            on
                pe_all.timeIn <= pe.timeIn and
                (
                    pe_all.timeOut > pe.timeIn or
                    pe_all.timeOut is null
                )
    group by pe.timeIn
), Ranked as (
    select *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Cnt desc) as rnk
    from PossibleMaxima
)
select * from Ranked where rnk =  1
```

This assumes that all login events can be paired with logout events, and that you don't have stray extras (a logout without a login, or two logins in a row without a logout).

It works by generating 3 [CTEs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The first, `PairedEvents` associates the login rows with their associated logout rows (and needs the above assumption).

Then, in `PossibleMaxima`, we take each login event and try to find any `PairedEvents` rows that overlap that time. The number of times that that join succeeds is the number of users who were concurrently online.

Finally, we have the `Ranked` CTE that gives the maximum value the rank of 1. If there are multiple periods that achieve the maximum then they will each be ranked 1 and returned in the final result set.

If it's possible for multiple users to have *identical* login times then a slight tweak to `PossibleMaxima` may be required - but that's only if we need to.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The CTEs seem to be causing problem in the platform I'm running the sql which has a bit of abstraction over Sql Server.  Can it be changed to work without CTEs  as it would in Sql server 2005(with inner queries)?

Comment: How about the query to count all the logins before each logout record and then get the maximum count of them?